# How to insert link in SMS Campaign in SAP Marketing?

Tags: hyperlink, sms, sap-marketing-cloud

In *SAP Marketing*, I have the standard template for SMS messages in Content Studio.

I want to insert a link in TEXT-block of this template and send it via SMS, but there's a problem: for TEXT-block, there are no properties active that are necessary, except of "Insert Attribute".  I can't find "Insert Link" attribute.

SMS Template in Content Studio (What I have now):
[image: SMS Template]

I want to have this result in the end because there's a property which makes it possible to insert a link in TEXT-block:
[image: What I want]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of emails, where you send HTML, SMS contain simple text.
If you click on the link-button in emails, the editor inserts an HTML-element:

```
<a href="LINK TARGET">LINK TEXT</a>
```

But luckily, most of the smartphones are highlighting links without you have to mark it as a link.
This is very similar to what happens with phone numbers or dates in SMS.

**So you just have to paste in your link and you are fine.**

Here you see how my iPhone renders an SMS from my provider informing me about my left data volume: nothing. :-(

[image: SMS from my provider informing me about my left data volume: nothing :-(]